# Is there a test case scenario in which my program will fail?

Tags: java, arrays, testing, arraylist

**Problem** : You have L, a list containing some digits (0 to 9). Write a function solution(L) which finds the largest number that can be made from some or all of these digits and is divisible by 3. If it is not possible to make such a number, return 0 as the solution. L will contain anywhere from 1 to 9 digits.  The same digit may appear multiple times in the list, but each element in the list may only be used once.

**Test Cases :**

Input:
Solution.solution({3, 1, 4, 1})
Output: 4311

Input:
Solution.solution({3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9})
Output: 94311

**My Program :**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Solution {


    static ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> largest = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static int o = 1;
    static int po = 0;

    static void combinations(String[] digits, String[] data, int start, int end, int index, int r)
    {

        if (index == r)
        {
            String temp = "0";
            for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
            {
                temp = temp + data[j];
                //  System.out.print(data[j]);
            }
            Integer d = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            al.add(d);
//            System.out.println(al);
        }

        for (int i = start; i <= end && ((end - i + 1) >= (r - index)); i++)
        {
            data[index] = digits[i];
            combinations(digits, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r);
        }
    }

    static void printCombinations(String[] sequence, int N)
    {
        String[] data = new String[N];
        for (int r = 0; r < sequence.length; r++)
            combinations(sequence, data, 0, N - 1, 0, r);
    }

    static String[] convert(int[] x)
    {
        String c[] = new String[x.length];
        for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            Integer k = x[i];
            if(k==0)
            {
                o = o * 10;
                continue;
            }
            c[i] = k.toString();
        }
//        System.out.println(o);

        c = Arrays.stream(c).filter(s -> (s != null && s.length() > 0)).toArray(String[]::new);
        po = c.length;

//        System.out.println("Come"+ Arrays.asList(c));
        return c;
    }

    public static int solution(int[] l) {

        if(l.length==0)
            return 0;

        if(IntStream.of(l).sum()%3==0)
        {
            String x = "";
            Arrays.sort(l);
            for (int i = l.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                x = x + l[i];
            }
            return Integer.parseInt(x);
        }

        printCombinations(convert(l),po);

        al.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
        al.remove(al.size()-1);
        al.removeIf( num -> num%3!=0);
        if(al.isEmpty())
            return 0;
        for(int i=0; i< al.size(); i++)
        {
            Integer n =  al.get(i);
            printMaxNum(n);
        }
        //   System.out.println(al);
        //   System.out.println(largest);

        return largest.get(0)*o;
    }

    static void printMaxNum(int num)
    {
        // hashed array to store count of digits
        int count[] = new int[10];

        // Converting given number to string
        String str = Integer.toString(num);

        // Updating the count array
        for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
            count[str.charAt(i)-'0']++;

        // result is to store the final number
        int result = 0, multiplier = 1;

        // Traversing the count array
        // to calculate the maximum number
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            while (count[i] > 0)
            {
                result = result + (i * multiplier);
                count[i]--;
                multiplier = multiplier * 10;
            }
        }

        // return the result
        largest.add(result);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(solution(new int[]{9,8,2,3}));


    }

}
```

My Code passes both given test cases and 3 other hidden test cases except one. I tried all possible input combinations but couldn't get to the exact failure. The return type by default is given as int and therefore they would not pass values which give output that does not fit in int. Any other scenario where my code fails?

Comment: if your code is written well, and you covered every possible option, no, otherwise, might be. Do understand this is not a code review service

Comment: pass null's, for instance, see what 'll happen.

Comment: I added a condition to handle null values to return 0 and submitted. But still that 1 case is not passing